# How do I change the kernel

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, kernel

I have to get an old image from a physical ubuntu (dapper) box into AWS.
The software stack and applications are not exactly contemporary so I have tried to do a P2V to AWS

dd'd the /dev/sda volume ok
Mounted it on another ubuntu AWS instance to fix up ssh keys, fstab, networking etc

but now it won't boot ( not that I am surprised )
says:

```
Tpmfront:Error Unable to read device/vtpm/0/backend-id during tpmfront initialization! error =     ENOENT Tpmfront:Info Shutting down tpmfront 
xc: error: panic: xc_dom_bzimageloader.c:655:     
xc_dom_probe_bzimage_kernel: boot protocol too old (0204): Invalid kernel xc: error: panic:  
xc_dom_core.c:621: xc_dom_find_loader: no loader found: Invalid kernel
```

How do I change the kernel (manually) to a more AWS friendly version?

Answer (score 0):

AWS has a guide for making AWS friendly Kernels.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UserProvidedKernels.html

If this box is too old for that. You're going to have to either clone it out and try a dist-upgrade. Or simply port your apps onto a brand spanking new AWS machine.

Word of advice for the future. LTS. That way you have 5 years to deal with this.